# Apps Script to get a value from another spreadsheet but also keep the formatting (red font)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been looking all day for a way to use getValue or getDisplayValue to be able to keep the formatting that I am pulling into another spreadsheet with Apps Script. The source cell contains words in red text, and when I pull it in with either getValue or get DisplayValue, I lose the red color. Is there a way to do this within the original code or would I have to write a second function to find those specific cells in the new file with that wording, and then make them red?

Comment: You can copy the entire sheet temporarily and then use copyTo() and then delete the temporary sheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy value and format from a sheet to a new google Spreadsheet document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106580/copy-value-and-format-from-a-sheet-to-a-new-google-spreadsheet-document)

Comment: I am just looking to get a few cells from several spreadsheets and then combine them into one list. One of the source cells is in red, but when it pulls it into the new combined spreadsheet, it is no longer red.