# How to make a copy of a Google spreadsheet with formulas, not only values?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a master Google Sheet with formulas. The user enters some details and the script then makes a copy of the sheet using the copy method:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var tmpSS = ss.copy(bookID + "-" + title);
```

When I open the new spreadsheet, there are only values in the cells, the formulas have not been copied over. How do I copy over the formulas as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
    var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetId();

    DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId).makeCopy("SheetName");
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned here: [GAS-copyto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864831/google-apps-script-copyto-using-contentsonlytrue-not-working), the method *copyTo* on *sheet* should make a copy of the sheet with values and formulae. So maybe you could write a loop to create copies of all sheets of a given spreadsheet, using this.

Comment: The problem is because he is expecting to copy a formula with a function that only copies actual data and formatting

Comment: @Vytautas  That's incorrect. copyTo does copy formulae

Comment: I retract my statement, a test shows that indeed it can copy formula. My answer still stands, using `.getFormulas()` and `.setFormulas()` will work

Comment: Thanks for the replies but I must be missing something. I used the following code and the newly created spreadsheet only shows values, not formulas and values. 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var tmpSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(bookID + "-" + title);
      sheet.copyTo(tmpSS);
do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()) you can use `.getFormulas()` and `.setFormulas()` to copy over formulas. You can copy to any sheet or spreadsheet you have access to.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.